# ByReference useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, pass-by-reference

Using mui-material, i'm collapsing a table row using this line

```
<Collapse in={"open"+row.name} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
```

I have a useState

```
const [openOne, setOpenOne] = useState(false)
```

during the `.map` iteration, the first row.name would be `One` so in the collpase it would create like `in={openOne}`

My problem is how do I reference the `{"open"+row.name}` which would be `{openOne}` to the useState `openOne`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a different approach.

Maybe instead of using a different `useState` for each item, you should use one that hold the values for all of them.

```js
const [openRows, setOpenRows] = useState(()=>{
   // replace allRows with the list of rows you have
   allRows.reduce((acc, {name})=>({
     ...acc,
     [name]: false
   }),{});
});
```

now you can use

```js
<Collapse in={openRows[row.name]} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
```

and to set a row, you can do

```js
setOpenRows((currentOpen) => ({
  ...currentOpen,
  'one': true  // or [row.name]: true if you are using it in a dynamic way
}));
```